# Use old database for CRUD and new database for receiveng the same data

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, message-queue

Here is the task I want to solve - we have a server using database (A) and the application that uses that, now I need to create a new server with the new database (B) and have the same data as in the (A) with the same relations and ids and everything else. The point is I need to use (A) for CRUD and B for receiving data, so they always should be the same (synced). What is the best way and practice to achieve such logic and connection?
So far I think about this way: create a dump of (A), then restore in (B) => use something like RabbitMQ or Kafka when CRUD data in (A) to update data in (B). But I see some cons here: what if data in (B) are not updated? I know we have Retries when using queues but it doesn't mean that for a 100% data are being updated in (B). And how to handle such cases when server (B) crushed but (A) is still working correctly and handling CRUD => which causes data inconsistency?
If that helps - databases PostgreSql and server apps are created using Nodejs frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PG logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html#:%7E:text=Logical%20replication%20is%20a%20method,byte%2Dby%2Dbyte%20replication.)

Comment: Can't do that with docker containers.